# Android: Vector drawable is not repeating

Tags: android, xml

I am using below code. "@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" is vector image and below you can see xml for bitmap and also you can see Error in screen shot thanks .

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use vector image you have to set the attribute with `srcCompat` as:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
```

But since `src` is the required attribute of the bitmap and you can not set vector image to `src`. Thus you have to use .png or any other image type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running/building the app. Often you can have the automatic xml renderer fail however the app will still build fine.